# request.user is giving me only email address but I want all information of user using email primary key as

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

whenever is authenticated user post in My device I've to check id the device is associated with this user or not? for that, I've get all the information using request.user, but instead I am just getting an email address, is there any solution for this?

## My custom User model

```
class User(AbstractUser):
"""User model."""

  username = None
  email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
  mobile_token = models.CharField(max_length=20,blank=True,null=True)

  USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
  REQUIRED_FIELDS = []



  objects = UserManager_1()
```

## My device model

```
  class Device(models.Model):
# user_id = models.CharField(max_length=20,primary)
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=20 ,primary_key=True )

    email = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank = True,null=True)

    date_added = models.DateField(default=timezone.now)



   def __str__(self):
     return self.device_id
```

## My serailzers

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
# my_field = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

# def get_field_name(self, obj):
#     return "name"

   class Meta:
     model = models.User
     # key= {'status':'success'}

      fields = ('first_name', 'email','last_name','mobile_token',)
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    # locations = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True, 
      queryset=models.User.objects.all())

      class Meta:
        model = models.Device

        fields = ('date_added','email','device_id',)
```

## And The View for device

```
class DeviceView(viewsets.ViewSet):


   queryset = models.Device.objects.all()


   serializer_class = serializers.DeviceSerializer

   def list(self,request):
    queryset = models.Device.objects.all()
    serializer = serializers.DeviceSerializer(queryset, many=True)
    final_data = serializer.data


    import json


    api={}
    api['data'] = final_data
    api['message'] = "Device ids"
    # Device_name_api = final_data[]
    # validators = serializer.get_validators()
    api['status'] = 1
    # print(request.data)
    return Response(api)
   def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    # response = super().post(request, *args, **kwargs)
    # print(self.response)
    serializer = self.serializer_class(data=request.data)

    print(request.user)
    # user_data=models.User.objects.all()
    # print(user_data)
    # print(request.META['HTTP_X_MYHEADER'])
    # print(request.data['device_id'])

    if serializer.is_valid():

        return Response({
                'data':serializer.data,
                'status': 1,
                'message': 'Succuess'
            }, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Comment: What are all data you send to the particular view?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [`depth`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#specifying-nested-serialization) option:

```
class DeviceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

      class Meta:
        model = models.Device

        fields = ('date_added','email','device_id',)
        depth = 1
```

Comment: Thanks, now I have one simple question in django-rest-auth is there any method that we can check if the email is verified or not, if email is not verified but login credentials are right then I want to send message that please verify your mail first

Comment: @Kashyap you can write custom auth backend for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#handling-authorization-in-custom-backends  Or simple add to the model boolean field `email_verified` and check it on view level like this: `if user.email_verified`.

Comment: I've already have email_verified but it's on a different table(email addresses table) not in User table

Comment: @Kashyap you need to provide additional information such as email address model. I suppose it would be better to do it in different question.